# Disable WC Bookings automatic order completion

Tags: plugins, woocommerce-offtopic, filters

WooCommerce Bookings has this feature that automatically changes the order status from processing to completed once the payment is confirmed.

I'm trying to find a way to disable it, so it can work like it usually do on standard WooCommerce.

Searching the code of the plugin, I was able to find this filter:

```
class WC_Booking_Order_Manager {
  public function __construct() {
    add_filter( 'woocommerce_payment_complete_order_status', array( $this, 'complete_order' ), 20, 2 );
  }
}
```

I'm sure I only have to remove this filter, but can't figure out how to do it since I don't know what variable holds the instance of this class.

I also have found where this class is instantiated:

```
class WC_Bookings {
  private function init() {
    new WC_Booking_Order_Manager();
  }
}
```

Is there a variable holding this class instance?
How can I access it?
Is there any other way to remove this filter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've been doing some research and it seems to be a bad practice from the WC Bookings team to instantiate a class without assigning it to a variable.

But knowing just that doesn't help me in this case.

Fortunately, I was able to find [this comment](https://hardcorewp.com/2012/enabling-action-and-filter-hook-removal-from-class-based-wordpress-plugins/#comment-9756) from @MikeSchinkel where he teaches and presents a function on how to remove a filter of an anonymous object.

This is how I implemented it in my case. First, the original function found in Mike's comment:

```
if ( ! function_exists( 'remove_anonymous_object_filter' ) ) {
  /**
   * Remove an anonymous object filter.
   *
   * @param string $tag Hook name.
   * @param string $class Class name
   * @param string $method Method name
   *
   * @return void
   *
   */
  function remove_anonymous_object_filter( $tag, $class, $method ) {
    $filters = false;

    if ( isset( $GLOBALS['wp_filter'][$tag] ) )
      $filters = $GLOBALS['wp_filter'][$tag];

    if ( $filters )
      foreach ( $filters as $priority => $filter ) {
        foreach ( $filter as $identifier => $function ) {
          if ( ! is_array( $function ) )
            continue;
          if ( ! $function['function'][0] instanceof $class )
            continue;
          if ( $method == $function['function'][1] ) {
            remove_filter( $tag, array( $function['function'][0], $method ), $priority );
          }
        }
      }
  }
}
```

Finally, the call to the removal of the filter:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_payment_complete_order_status', 'unhook_booking_complete_order', 0 );
function unhook_booking_complete_order($status) {
  remove_anonymous_object_filter( 'woocommerce_payment_complete_order_status', 'WC_Booking_Order_Manager', 'complete_order' );
  return $status;
}
```

Basically, we are filtering `woocommerce_payment_complete_order_status` again whith a higher priority in order to remove the filter manually (with the `remove_anonymous_object_filter` function) based in its hook, class name and method.

All credits to Mike and the original answer that inspired his code.

Comment: Seems to work fine on WP 4.7+. Tested using 5.3.1.